# How to save records for 2 models within the same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I let users share reflections. After a reflection is saved, I would like to save another record (to an Activity table) that will be used to have a list of all recent activities taken.

The reflection is saving properly, but I am calling another table (Activity) after reflection is saved and am not able to get this record saved. What am I doing wrong here?

```
if @reflection.save
  list_of_receivers = Grouplookup.where(group_id: @reflection.group_ids)

  # Receiver ID - iterate through users in group that we're sharing through
  list_of_receivers.each do |receiver|
    if receiver.user_id != current_user.id
      @activity = Activity.new
      @activity.poster = current_user.id
      @activity.receiver = receiver.user_id
      @activity.reflection = @reflection.id
      @activity.save
    end
  end
end
```

In the code above, Activity is not getting saved. When I check the logs after a reflection is saved, there is no mention of Activity anywhere.

Comment: Try checking if there's some validation error. Replace the `@activity.save` with `@activity.valid?` and add `@activity.errors`.

Comment: I just tried that and nothing firing. There is no mention of "Activity" in the logs at all, which is very strange.

Comment: Maybe `receiver.user_id != current_user.id` is always returning `false`.

Comment: I put the activity code outside of this block (and even on a completely different page) and it still doesn't get called...

Comment: What's on the logs at that point?

Comment: If you change your query to `Grouplookup.where(group_id: @reflection.group_ids).where.not(user_id: current_user.id)` you can remove the `if statement` inside each block.

Comment: basic debugging, sprinkle `puts` statements around the code and find what variables are not meeting your expectations... is `list_of_receivers.length` non-zero?, what are the values of `receiver.user_id`? etc etc.

Comment: as style comment... this kind of code really should be a callback (`after_save`) on the Reflection model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `save!` insteaf of default `save`, you will be sure that `@activity.save` is executed, save with bang on the end will raise an error if record couldn't be saved